# How to convert sinusoidal to EPSG:4326 using GDAL in the polar regions of MODIS 43A4?

Tags: gdal

I'm using GDAL to create EPSG:4326 geometries (polygon or multipolygon) from MODIS rasters in sinusoidal.  The script below works for tiles on the antimeridian (returning a multipolygon split by the antimeridian) *except* for vertical bands v00, v01, v16, and v17:

```
gdal_translate 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD43A4.A2017174.h13v01.006.2017187183922.hdf":MOD_Grid_BRDF:Nadir_Reflectance_Band1' band.tif
gdaltindex -tileindex location band-extent.shp band.tif
ogr2ogr  -segmentize 100000 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -lco RFC7946=YES -lco WRITE_BBOX=YES band-epsg4326.geojson band-extent.shp
```

In those 4 bands, I get a Polygon instead of a MultiPolygon, but with coordinates that would seem to be correct were it not for the "connecting" square in the middle:

[image: polygon]

Perhaps there's GDAL flag that I'm missing? Or maybe those polar regions need to be handled specially?

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be the "segmentize" value -- decreasing this to 25000 resulted in a correct MultiPolygon.